# SSL/TLS and VPN-SSL?

Tags: vpn, dns, ssl, tcp, tls

As I understand it, SSL/TLS is used when we visit a website using https. However, using this method only encrypts the data and not the IP address of the website we're requesting.

If you use a VPN secured with SSL/TLS, then this WILL prevent somebody (who is sniffing) from seeing the IP addresses of your website request?

Also, with the VPN-SSL I presume because DNS is on the application layer (along with http) the VPN would also prevent sniffers from discovering which website youre visiting from checking your DNS requests?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, everything inside the tunnel is protected. Observers can see the address of the tunnel endpoint.

However the tunnel ends somewhere and from there your TCP connection has to reach a webserver, the destination of that part of the journey can be observed. Someone might be able to correlate the two sets of activity.

Comment: I understand a VPN-SSL is easier to configure than IPSec: What if I wanted to rent a VPN-SSL Server to be one end of my tunnel and the other end would be my client. Would I need software on my client, or would I use my browser to connect to my "rented server" and then browse the internet via that, a bit like those proxy websites?

Comment: Moreover, a third-party cookie set during a non-VPN-protected browser session can also be accessed inside a VPN-protected session, essentially exposing your identity... VPN is not a panacea, it is only a part of a bigger solution (separate browser, etc.).

Comment: Trevor: Depends on the OS...Windows has no native SSL-VPN support whereas Linux does through OpenVPN. I believe you're still confusing a true VPN versus an SSL-capable proxy. In your case you probably would be better off with a proxy.

Comment: @gman, to be honest i havent seen a good explanation of how SSL/https is different to SSL-VPN?? When I read SSL-VPN documentation they just gloss over the 'VPN' bit?? look at this: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6586/ps6657/IOS_SSL_VPN_TDM_v8-jz-an.pdf

Comment: This question was just recently asked and answered here on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/373196/ssl-tls-vs-ssl-tls-vpn/373204#373204